# Are fields of the same type and access level contiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

Suppose I have a class with two fields of the same access level and type; if I have a pointer `p` to the first one, will `p + 1` invariably be a pointer to the second? e.g. for a class

```
class A {

public:
  B first;
  B second;

};
```

If I then have `A a;` and `B *p = &(a.first);`, are there any situations in which `(p + 1) == &(a.second)` could be false? Does the same apply to member pointers (e.g. `B A::*p = &A::first` and `(p + 1) == &A::second`)?

As a larger case, suppose I'm trying to recreate `std::array` without using builtin arrays. I might try something like this:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
class array {

  T head;
  array<T, N - 1> rest;

public:

  // ... and all the constructors and methods and whatnot

};

template<class T>
class array<T, 1> {

  T head;

public:

  // ...

};

template<class T>
class array<T, 0> {

public:

  // ...

};
```

(the special case for 1 is because `sizeof(array<T, 0>)` is `1` just like any other empty class, meaning that if it is included in the recursion then `sizeof(array<T, N>)` is `sizeof(T) * N + 1` instead of the expected `sizeof(T) * N`)

Given the above class definition, can I safely define the class's `T& operator [](size_t index)` simply to return `*(&head + index)`?

(I realize I could define it to return `index ? rest[index - 1] : head`, but the recursion would incur some significant overhead, and even if it's tail-call optimized or inlined, it still effectively becomes `index ? (index - 1 ? (index - 2 ? ... : rest.rest.head) : rest.head) : head` which still involves a lot more jumps than the pointer arithmetic version)

**Note: I am not asking if this should be done, but if it can; I am not planning on applying this, I'm just curious. Also, my question is just about the pointer arithmetic stuff, not anything else in my examples.**

Comment: Nope. Padding can be introduced by the compiler for alignment.

Comment: Even if the members are contiguous, you cannot use the pointer that results from `p+1`. While it may have the same address as the second member, dereferencing is still undefined behavior. *How* you get the pointer matters, it's not enough to just have the address.